# django-rest-framework-jwt: "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'write_only'"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a restful API to login to my Django site using [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org). As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317899/how-do-i-create-a-login-api-using-django-rest-framework) I'm trying to use [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt).

In my `settings.py` I added `'rest_framework'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

and I added

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token'),
```

to my url patterns, as specified in the django-rest-framework-jwt doc.

Now when I try to connect to my site I get the following error:

```
File "/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/views.py" in <module>
  7. from .serializers import JSONWebTokenSerializer
File "/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py" in <module>
  11. class JSONWebTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
File "/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py" in JSONWebTokenSerializer
  18.     password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
File "/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in __init__
  453.         super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'write_only'
```

Any suggestion anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your DRF's version. 'write_only' field parameter was added in version 2.3.11. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes