# How can I use SessionAuthentication to make a login rest API with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to do a rest api to be able to login to my Django app (from an Android app) using a request like

```
curl -X POST -d "username=myusername&password=mypassword" http://localhost:12345/rest/api-auth/login/
```

which should return a session id that I can use in future requests. It seems that I should use the SessionAuthentication authentication scheme, but there is [no doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#sessionauthentication) about it.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21317899/326849), but I'd like not to use any other app.

Any suggestion/pointer?

Answer (score 15):

The `/api-auth/login/` resource is only for authentication in the browseble api.
To use session authentication, you must create a session first.
You must have a login resource, which accepts user credentials and authenticates a user, using the Django authentication system.
On requesting that resource the client will get a cookie header.
The cookie and csrf token must be used in future requests.

```
curl -v -X POST https://example.com/api/user/login/ -d 'username=user&password=pass'

...

> Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=TqIuhp8oEP9VY32tUDcfQyUwn3cqpYCa; expires=Fri, 15-May-2015 12:48:57 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
> Set-Cookie:  sessionid=4yb4s456lbvd974oijbdha7k3l6g52q3; expires=Fri, 30-May-2014 12:48:57 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
```

DRF supports basic authentication too. You can use it to authenticate
user initially and create session. Here is an example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class MyBasicAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        user, _ = super(MyBasicAuthentication, self).authenticate(request)
        login(request, user)
        return user, _


class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, MyBasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': unicode(request.user),
            'auth': unicode(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: So I have to do a custom view for my API? there is no such thing included in Django REST framework?

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use that? I copied your code, added `url(r'^rest/login/$', views.ExampleView.as_view()),` to my urls.py and get `'NoneType' object is not iterable` in `user, _ = super(MyBasicAuthentication, self).authenticate(request)` when trying `curl -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/login/ -d "user=user&password=pass"`

Comment: You can use that particular implementation this way: `curl -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/login/ -u user:pass` That's how you authenticate with curl using basic authentication.

Comment: It seems that the view does not return (I get no response from `curl -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/login/ -u user:pass`). And how can I get a session from that?

Comment: @jul I have the same problem now, I posted a question about this and I didnt get the answer, how you implemented this?

Comment: I used `TokenAuthentication` in the end.

Comment: I dont know how to contact you, but can you help me?! I'm lost :(

Comment: `/rest/api` -> Page not found (404)

Comment: The method "def get" is linked to the http request being made in that view? If yes, then is it possible to save this method elsewhere to be reused by other views, instead of having to put it in every single view where you want to make sure the user is logged in?

Comment: How do I add a session duration? Like invalidate a session after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Django REST docs say BasicAuth is only for testing

Answer (score 2):

For using in android it is better to use Token Authentication.
I've used Session Authentication in my Django sites that are Rectified.

Here the login api is called, which stored a session id.
You can call then any other APIs.

You need to enable Session Authentication in settings

`settings.py`

```py
# Rest Framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'
}
```

Here's the login api (function based view):

```py
# accounts/views.py
import json

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import JsonResponse

@api_view(['POST',])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login_view(request):
    """
    POST API for login
    """
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')
    if username is None:
        return JsonResponse({
            "errors": {
                "detail": "Please enter username"
            }
        }, status=400)
    elif password is None:
        return JsonResponse({
            "errors": {
                "detail": "Please enter password"
            }
        }, status=400)

    # authentication user
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return JsonResponse({"success": "User has been logged in"})
    return JsonResponse(
        {"errors": "Invalid credentials"},
        status=400,
    )
```

here is the url.py file

```py
# accounts/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from .api_views import login_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('api-auth/login/', login_view, name="api-auth-login"),
]
```

Answer (score -2):

If the intention is to access some endpoint by passing the username&password on the POST data, you can do the following:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^stuff/', views.MyView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from rest_framework import viewsets
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework.views import APIView    
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
    from rest_framework import exceptions
    from rest_framework import authentication
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
    from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication, 
SessionAuthentication


class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):

        # Get the username and password
        username = request.data.get('username', None)
        password = request.data.get('password', None)

        if not username or not password:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('No credentials provided.'))

        credentials = {
            get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD: username,
            'password': password
        }

        user = authenticate(**credentials)

        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('Invalid username/password.'))

        if not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('User inactive or deleted.'))


    return (user, None)  # authentication successful


class MyView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, ExampleAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):    
        content = {
            'user': unicode(request.user),
            'auth': unicode(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

**Curl**

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8000/stuff/ -d 'username=my_username&password=my_password'
```

Comment: you override def authenticate() and waiting than all time can get username and password but i don't enter username and password when switching to a new url , i have only sessionId, so your variant is not working