# Django's SessionAuthentication don't working

Tags: python, django, session, django-rest-framework

I want to use `SessionAuthentication` but enough documentation or clear explanation is absent. I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687643/how-can-i-use-sessionauthentication-to-make-a-login-rest-api-with-django-rest-fr) and [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication), and [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#permissions), and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions) but it no has answer for my question.
My understanding is one of the reasons - `IsAuthenticated`, because it always return *AnonymousUser* in `request.user` and *None* in `request.auth`.
So i need a help.

*urls.py*

```
from rest_framework import routers

from accounts.views.user import AuthViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register('', AuthViewSet, basename='auth')

account_urlpatterns = router.urls
```

part of *views/user.py*

```
User = get_user_model()



class AuthViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    serializer_class = (EmptySerializer, )
    serializer_classes = {
        'login': UserLoginSerializer,
        'registration': UserRegisterSerializer,
        'passwd_change': PasswordChangeSerializer
    }
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @action(methods=['POST', ], detail=False)
    def login(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = get_and_authenticate_user(**serializer.validated_data)
        data = AuthUserSerializer(user).data
        login(request, user, 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication')
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @action(methods=['POST', ], detail=False)
    def registration(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = create_user_account(**serializer.validated_data)
        data = AuthUserSerializer(user).data
        login(request, user, 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication')
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @action(methods=['POST', ], detail=False, permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, ])
    def logout(self, request):
        logout(request)
        data = {'success': 'Sucessfully logged out'}
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=False)
    def passwd_change(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        request.user.set_password(serializer.validated_data['new_password'])
        request.user.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

*serializers/login.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = None
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
```

*serializers/password.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation


class PasswordChangeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    current_password = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=128)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=128)
```

part of *setting.py*

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

i open *http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/login* enter login/password and get a `sessionid`:
[image]

then i open *http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/passwd_change* `sessionid` is here and page for change password opens (I just specifically delete `permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, ]` in decorator to make the page open):
[image]

then i click button POST and get *AnonymousUser* although `sessionid` is here too:
[image]

cookies are allowed in the browser:
[image]

Do have any idea how to win it ?
Don't propose variants with `JWT` and `Tokens`, please, i need `SessionAuthentication` variant only.